# Rank functions: How to 'restart' counting

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, rank

I am struggling with the following issue. Given the below table, I need to group my sales correctly. The table is ordered using PeriodYear, and PeriodWeek.

The logic is as follows:
'Group by Product, PriceShopGroup, BasePrice, Unit Price within continuoes timeframes.'

1. If PeriodWeek is continuous and the values of Product, PriceShopGroup, BasePrice, Unit Price are the same, it's one group.
2. If there is a break between weeks(difference between previous and current PeriodWeek>1), it's a new group.
3. If PeriodWeek is continuous and the values of Product, PriceShopGroup, BasePrice, Unit Price change, it's a new group.

I have covered most of that. However, what happens, is that I need to assign a new product group if my sequence was broken. That means, in the below example, the last row is the only one wrong. It should have a new product group, despite having the same Product, PriceShopGroup, BasePrice, Unit Price as other rows that belong to group 21. The reason for that is the sequence was broken with a unit price of 0.55. Hope that's clear, and thank you for any advice!

[image: strong text]

```
period_lag_window = Window.partitionBy('Price_Shop_Group', 'Product').orderBy("Period_Year", "Period_Week")

time_gap_expr = when(((col("Period_Week")-col("PreviousWeek"))>1) & (col("Period_Year")==col("PreviousYear")), 1).otherwise(0)

lag_applied = initial_df.withColumn('PreviousWeek', lag(initial_df['Period_Week']).over(period_lag_window)).withColumn('PreviousYear', lag(initial_df['Period_Year']).over(period_lag_window))

is_timegap = lag_applied.withColumn("TimeGap", time_gap_expr)
cum_sum = is_timegap.withColumn('TimePeriodGroup', sum('TimeGap').over(Window.partitionBy('Price_Shop_Group', 'Product').orderBy('Period_Year', 'Period_Week').rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))

window = Window.partitionBy("Price_Shop_Group", "Product").orderBy("Product", "Price_Shop_Group", "Base_Price", "Unit_Price","TimePeriodGroup") 

ranked_df = (
  cum_sum.withColumn("ProductGroup", dense_rank().over(window))
              )
```

Comment: Update your question providing the dataframe creation as code, not an image